# Connect more than one android devices without USB(using wifi) is it possible?

Tags: android, adb

I follow following steps for the connecting my device and already go-through this link [Adb over wireless without usb cable at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327839/adb-over-wireless-without-usb-cable-at-all) and [Connecting two android devices using wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445168/connecting-two-android-devices-using-wifi) still not connected and this onle also [adb error: more than one device - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269473/adb-error-more-than-one-device-android)

- I connect my device to my computer via USB cable.
- Go to platform tool path.
- Run adb tcpip 5555.
- Disconnect my device (remove the USB cable).
- I Go to the Settings -> About phone -> Status to view the IP address of my phone.
- Run adb connect :5555.

I get this **error on terminal**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
You have to provide the device id as well to open adb over wifi when more than 1 device is connected.

```
adb -s <device ID> tcpip 5555
```

I got the asnwer from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38348791/4428159

provide your phone ip as well:

`adb: usage: adb connect <host>[:<port>]`

host is the ip address of the mobile you want to connect.
You have to do this for all the devices you want to connect to.

Comment: my first device is connected properly but issue about my second device it giving error on command prompt more than one emulator or device.

Comment: Oh ok, then go to developers setting in your phone and turn on the *adb over network* on manually. It will work for now. I will test the scenario you have given above with usb cable and let you know